# how to set background color in excel js, depending on the value?

Tags: node.js, exceljs

How can I get the values of a column and paint the background color depending on the value.
I have the column: "Stock" and I need to know when the value is 0 to make the background red.
in this way I paint the first row of the header. Is it possible to implement the logic to obtain the mentioned values?

```
ws.eachRow((row, rowNumber) => {
row.eachCell((cell) => {
  console.log(rowNumber);
  if (rowNumber == 1) {
    cell.fill = {
      type: "pattern",
      pattern: "solid",
      fgColor: { argb: "2563EB" },
    };
  }

  cell.font = {
    color: { argb: "FFFFFF" },
    bold: true,
  };

  cell.border = {
    top: { style: "thin" },
    left: { style: "thin" },
    bottom: { style: "thin" },
    right: { style: "thin" },
  };
});
row.commit();
});

ws.addRows(arrProducts);
.......
```